# How to use Mapsforge online mode

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap

How can I implement map in my android app. using mapsforge lib (avoiding the creation of map or reading a map file) ?
Can I download tiles from OSM server ?

In [this](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapView) article they demonstrate only offline mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tile downloading feature has been removed. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mapsforge-dev/0dGCdh5jHmw/z-zKBcp9CHUJ) on the mapsforge mailing list. If you only need that specific feature, you can revert to an older revision. I can't remember the exact revision but it should be a revision that was released about one month before the linked comment.

Comment: The tile download feature was removed because [the tile server went down](http://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/dev/2012-February/024301.html). I think instead of tile downloads we need to create a vector downloader that would feed the renderer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Mapsforge's sample code at https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/source/browse.

[`DownloadLayerViewer`](https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/source/browse/Applications/Android/Samples/src/main/java/org/mapsforge/applications/android/samples/DownloadLayerViewer.java) demonstrates how to get tiles from the OSM Mapnik server. (Do check OSM's [Tile Usage Policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_Usage_Policy) before using this in an app!)

There is also a class for OpenCycleMap, which works in the same way.

If you want to use a custom tile source, take a look at [`DownloadCustomLayerViewer`](https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/source/browse/Applications/Android/Samples/src/main/java/org/mapsforge/applications/android/samples/DownloadCustomLayerViewer.java). This example shows you how to specify the URL from which you want to donload the tiles.